# Graphics Editor using SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a project for school and have to build and graphics editor (something similar to paint) using SVG. I found the code for the functions in JavaScript to draw a circle, line, etc, but when I try to add them to a button onclick function it doesn't work.

```
function drawCircle(position) {
//     var radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((dragStartLocation.x - position.x), 2) + Math.pow((dragStartLocation.y - position.y), 2));
//     context.beginPath();
//     context.arc(dragStartLocation.x, dragStartLocation.y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
}
```

This is the HTML

```
<button onclick="drawCircle()" class="button">Dreptunghi</button>
```

Comment: your tag should be just `button` instead of `button1`. What is the expected result here? where is the value of `dragStartLocation` coming from?

Comment: the function i found on the internet. I have to make an grafic editor using svg. Add shapes like circle, elipse, rectangular, add and edit text, selection/delete/move/change the shapes have drawn.

Comment: I would say that it doesn't work because all your code is commented out.

Answer (score 1):

**Canvas (html5) Version**

You are trying to use `html5-canvas` but not `svg`.

If so:

1. Add a [`canvas`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) tag in your html.
2. Defined the `drawCircle` function like the code above.

```js
function drawCircle() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
  var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
  var radius = 70;

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = 'green';
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
  context.stroke();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="drawCircle()">Dreptunghi</button>
<br />
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

**Update**

**SVG Version**

```js
function drawCircle() {
  document.getElementById('svg').innerHTML = '<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="70" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" fill="green" />';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="drawCircle()">Dreptunghi</button>
<br /><br />
<svg height="200" width="578" id="svg"></svg>
```

---

For drawing with `SVG`, I recommend to use a library such as [svg.js](https://github.com/wout/svg.js)

```js
function drawCircle() {
  var draw = SVG('draw').size(578, 200);
  var circle = draw.circle(70).attr({fill:'green',stroke:'#003300', 'stroke-width': 5, cx:50, cy:50});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.2.5/svg.js"></script>
<button onclick="drawCircle()">Dreptunghi</button>
<br /><br />
<div id="draw"></div>
```

Comment: o.Pup is that the answer you looked for?